# Error 500 al iniciar sesion trabajando con mvc

Tags: php

Tengo este form en html, el logueo lo hago sin jquery ni ajax.
Mando de este form por post:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" style="vertical-align: central;" action="views/procesologin.php">
    <p>ACCESO AL SISTEMA</p>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="USUARIO"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contraseña</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="PASS"/>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="guardar"/>
     

</form>
```

Y en procesologin.php:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once ("C:\\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\models\claseLogin.php");


    $U1=new Login();
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $arrayu=$U1->User($usuario,$pass);
   
         if (count($arrayu)>1){ 
            
                foreach ($arrayu as $n){
           

         
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$n['nombre']; 
            $_SESSION['idlog']=$n['iduser']; 
               
                }
  
     
        header ("Location : ../index.php?controller=template&action=index");
            }
       

?>
```

En el index principal la primera vez aparece el login;

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gestionweb/routes.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){

    


 if (isset($_POST['controller'])&&isset($_POST['action'])) {

  $controller=$_POST['controller'];
  $action=$_POST['action'];
   
        call($controller,$action,$id);  
 }else{
    call("login","index",0); 
 }
}else{
    echo "no esta logueado en el sistema";
    call("login","index",0);
}
?>
```

Pero luego obtengo el error 500:
**¡Error del servidor!

Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor y no se ha podido completar su solicitud. Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor y no se ha podido completar su solicitud. O el servidor está sobrecargado o ha habido un fallo en la ejecución de un programa CGI.

Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.
Error 500**

Comment: coloca el error de apache para encontrar el problema, o activa los errores de PHP

Comment: como activo los errores de php?

Comment: la instruccion que da el problema o la ultima que puse es un redireccionamiento:  header ("Location : ../index.php");

Comment: estas suponiendo , y para poderte ayudar no puedo suponer

Comment: ok..ya active los errores de php y no me muestra nada en pantalla, no se que puedo hacer

Comment: busca el log de apache2 alli debe estar

Comment: me dice: AH02429: Response header name 'Location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: http://localhost/gestionweb/index.php?controller=template&action=index

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86297/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-caruso).